# Piper Cherokee - Flying with inoperative equipment

Tags: safety, ppl, equipment, piper-pa-28

I've looked everywhere and I'm not able to find the relevant information regarding the following.

What equipment can be inoperative and still allow me to fly a pa-28-181? I know the rules in the 91.213 and to placard the inoperative equipment, etc.

But my question is, which specific equipment is required for flying day/night VFR (PPL)? There is no MEL for most GA aircrafts, such as the pa-28-181s.

For example, if the landing light isn't working, I can probably still fly day VFR but I can't fly if the altimeter isn't working.

I was told that there is a flow checklist that helps answer whether a specific inoperative equipment is required or not for the cherokees but I can't find it. Any guidance would be helpful.

P.S.: I'm preparing for my checkride and am trying to checkoff the PA.I.B.K3a item on the ACS.

Comment: Depending on the type of airspace you’d be flying in, I don’t see why you’d need an altimeter.

Comment: @Jim - see FAR 91.205 (b)(2). Altimeter required.

Comment: @757toga -  Ok.  Required by regulation.  It’s been too long I guess…

Comment: Reviewing FAR 91.205, the PA-28-181 KOEL (Kinds of operations equipment list) in the POH), along with the references shown in the ACS (FAA-H-8083-2, FAA-H-8083-25) and FAR 91.213 should give you what you need.

Comment: Also, look at the FAA's AC 91-67 that has a **Flow Chart** that may be of the type you are interested in.

Comment: Ahh yes!! That's exactly what I was looking for FAA AC 91-67! @757toga . If you post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: apparently AC 91-67 has been cancelled.  But look at my answer to see if you can derive a benefit from the links I have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question: *What equipment can be inoperative and still allow me to fly a pa-28-181?*

---

AC 91-67 - **Minimum Equipment Requirements for General
Aviation Operations Under FAR Part 91** has been cancelled and has not been replaced (as far as I can tell).

However, you can refer to [AC 91-67 - Minimum Equipment Requirements for General Aviation Operations Under FAR Part 91
Document Information](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/22435), which shows this AC and the reason for its cancellation.

Also, helpful is this [FAA S Team](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/alc/course_content.aspx?cID=25&sID=102) training course entitled: **ALC-25: Flight Review Prep Guide**, which contains excellent information regarding aircraft airworthiness and should help in an understanding of what is necessary to respond to **PA.I.B.K3a** in the Private Pilot ACS.

**Relevant excerpt from the (U.S) Private Pilot ACS referred to in the question:**

[image]

Comment: Pleasse avoid link only answers, Links rot, quote the relevant parts of any linked document in the answer itself please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned 91.213, I'm going to assume you're talking about the US, since you didn't specify the jurisdiction.

The required equipment for VFR is outlined in [14 CFR § 91.205](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.205) The exact answer depends on the type of flight.

For VFR day flight, you will need:

> Airspeed indicator.
>
> Altimeter.
>
> Compass.
>
> Tachometer for each engine.
>
> Oil pressure gauge for each engine using oil.
>
> Temperature gauge for each liquid-cooled engine.
>
> Oil temperature gauge for each air-cooled engine.
>
> Manifold pressure gauge for each altitude (turbocharged) engine.
>
> Fuel gauge for each tank.
>
> Landing gear position indicator, if the aircraft has a retractable landing gear.
>
> An anticollision light system (if the plane was certificated after March 11, 1996).
>
> If operated for hire over water and beyond power-off gliding distance from shore, approved flotation gear.
>
> Seat belts
>
> An emergency locator transmitter.

For night VFR flight, you need all of the above, plus:

> Approved position lights.
>
> An anticollision light system (if certified after August 11, 1971).
>
> Landing light.
>
> An adequate source of electrical energy.
>
> One spare set of fuses, or three spare fuses of each kind required.

Answer (score 0):

In determining which equipment can be inoperative in flight the following information should be looked at:

1. 91.213 required equipment for day, night and IFR flight
2. Minimum equipment list - Items that can be inoperative and still be airworthy for dispatch)
3. Equipment list - Items installed at the time of certification.  Will list items that are required for dispatch and those items that are in addition to the requirements for dispatch
4. Kinds of operation list - Equipment required for a specific operation.

---

The PA-28 airplane most likely doesn't have a MEL.  It does have an equipment list as located in Section 6 of the POH.

[image: PA-28-161 Equipment List]